# Radio button list using editor templates for merging contacts

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, radio-button, radiobuttonlist, mvc-editor-templates

I am trying to display a form for merging two contacts in ASP.net MVC 5.
The form should look like this where each row holds a radio button group consisting of 2 options:

[image]

The form shows up just fine, and the radio groups work (I can select each group). However, when the model is posted back to the server, the `Values` list is empty (not preserved). I would like to get both the selected id but of course also the actual text value back in the controller. I prefer to do this using Editor Templates and if possible without `for` loops.

The current results (Values = null):

[image]

EDIT to respond to comments: I would prefer not to re-fetch the values in the controller again, because it results in a call to a web service. I have tried some variants of `HiddenFor` without results.

---

My **models** look like this:

```
public class Contact
{        
    public List<ContactRow> Rows { get; set; }
    public Contact()
    {
        this.Rows = new List<ContactRow>();
        this.Rows.Add(new ContactRow("First Name", "Homer", "Homie"));
        this.Rows.Add(new ContactRow("Last Name", "Simpson", "Simson"));
        this.Rows.Add(new ContactRow("Email", "mail1", "mail2"));
        this.Rows.Add(new ContactRow("Company Phone", "Phone1", "Phone2"));
        this.Rows.Add(new ContactRow("Mobile Phone", "Mobile1", "Mobile2"));
    }
}

public class ContactRow
{        
    public int Selection { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public List<ValueSet> Values { get; set; }

    public ContactRow(string Label, string LeftValue, string RightValue, int Selection = 0)
    {
        if (LeftValue== null) LeftValue= "";
        if (RightValue== null) RightValue= "";            
        this.Label = Label;
        this.Selection = Selection;
        this.Values = new List<ValueSet>(2);
        this.Values.Add(new ValueSet() { ID = 0, ValueText = LeftValue});
        this.Values.Add(new ValueSet() { ID = 1, ValueText = RightValue});            
    }

    public ContactRow() { }
}

public class ValueSet
{
    public int ID { set; get; }
    public string ValueText { set; get; }        
}
```

The **Controller**:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    Contact model = new Contact();
    return View(model);
}

public ActionResult MergeContacts(Contact model)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

And the **views**:

**Index.cshtml**

```
@model RadioTest.Models.Contact
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";    
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("MergeContacts", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { encType = "multipart/form-data", id = "contactDetailsForm", name = "contactDetailsForm" }))
{
<div>
    <table class="table" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <th style="text-align:left">Label</th>
            @*<th style="text-align:right">R1</th>*@
            <th style="text-align:left">
                Left Value
            </th>
            @*<th style="text-align:right">R2</th>*@
            <th style="text-align:left">
                Right Value
            </th>
        </tr>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Rows)
    </table>
    <input type="submit" />
</div>
}
```

Editor Template for ContactRow:

**ContactRow.cshtml**

```
@model RadioTest.Models.ContactRow

<tr>
    <td style="text-align:left">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Label)        
    </td>    
    @foreach (var v in Model.Values)    
    {
        <td style="text-align:left">
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Selection, v.ID) @v.ValueText            
        </td>
    }
</tr>

@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Label)
```

Comment: Your not rendering any controls for properties of `Values` so of course nothing post back. Not that you should be anyway, just get those values again in the controller when you post back.

Comment: The way you're loading values, it won't post list of `values`, Check the values of `Values` property in firebug/fiddler.

Comment: Thx for comments. Please see revised question

Comment: You need to change your way of loading controls `in-case of List`, can you post your complete `CSHTML` code ?

Comment: Not sure I understand, Moksh Shah. I have posted the entire relevant code. Note, it is a simple test project.

Comment: What are you actually wanting to do with this. Do you just want to return the selected value for a property (e.g. either "Homer" or "Homie" for the "First Name")?

Comment: Exactly, Stepen Muecke. The send the merged contact information to a web service.

Comment: Then I suspect this can be done a lot simpler (cant see why you need all this `LeftValue`, `RightValue`, `Selection` etc. properties). What is the model that your posting to the service (does it contain properties `FirstName`, `LastName` etc)?

Comment: First, I need to display the above form. The data comes from two different data sources (with different models). That is why I went with the Editor Template based approach and create a view model for it. If it can be done simpler, then I am open for suggestions. Otherwise, how can I make sure that the Value list is posted back to the server?

Comment: As for the `Value` list, you get it in the controller again (which is likely to be better performance that sending extra data to the view and then posting it back gain unchanged - and you can always put it in session). Is the intention that you get 2 contacts, then in the service add a new 'merged' contact and delete the 2 'old' ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your foreach to for:

```
@model MVCApp.Controllers.ContactRow 

<tr>
   <td style="text-align:left">
      @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Label)
   </td>
   @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Values.Count; i++)
   {
      <td style="text-align:left">
         @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Selection, Model.Values[i].ID)  @Model.Values[i].ValueText

         @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.Values[i].ID)
         @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.Values[i].ValueText)
      </td>
   }
</tr>

@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Label)
```

Comment: Just what I needed. Had tried this before without luck. I am aware that in some cases, the values should be fetched again in the controller, but this will do just fine in my case.